# How do I redefine `this` in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a function which is a JQuery event handler. Because it is a JQuery event handler, it uses the `this` variable to refer to the object on which it is invoked (as is normal for that library).

Unfortunately, I need to manually call that method at this point. How do I make `this` inside the called function behave as if it were called from JQuery?

Example code:

```
function performAjaxRequest() {
    //Function which builds AJAX request in terms of "this"
}

function buildForm(dialogOfForm) {
    var inputItem;
    dialogOfForm.html('...');
    dialogOfForm.dialog('option', 'buttons', {
        "Ok" : performAjaxRequest
    });
    inputItem = dialogOfForm.children(':not(label)');
    //Redirect enter to submit the form
    inputItem.keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            performAjaxRequest(); //Note that 'this' isn't the dialog box
                                  //as performAjaxRequest expects here, it's
                                  //the input element where the user pressed
                                  //enter!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `dialog` is the object that you need to be set to `this` then:

```
performAjaxRequest.apply(dialog, []); 
// arguments (instead of []) might be even better
```

should do the trick.

Otherwise, in jQuery you can simply call the [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method on the element that you want to have set to `this`

Say, for example, that you wanted to have a `click` event happen on a button and you need it to happen **now**.  Simply call:

```
$("#my_button").trigger("click");
```

Your `#my_button`'s `click` handler will be invoked, and `this` will be set to the `#my_button` element.

If you need to call a method with a different `this` ... say for example, with `this` referring to the jQuery object itself, then you will want to use `call` or `apply` on your function.

Chuck and meder have already given you examples of each ... but to have everything all in one place:

```
// Call
my_function.call(object_to_use_for_this, argument1, argument2, ... argumentN);

// Apply
my_function.apply(object_to_use_for_this, arguments_array);
```

SEE: [A List Apart's *Get Out of Binding Situations*](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations/)

Comment: Let's say I don't have a handy reference to the actual event or element on which the event would be fired.

Comment: @Billy ... so you want to trigger a variable event on a variable object or set of objects?  If so, what does the general code look like?  What *do* you know at the moment you want to trigger whatever it is you need to trigger?

Comment: Just updated the question -- let me know if that makes it clearer.

Comment: The question was, how to re-define 'this'. You did not answer the question.

Comment: `bind`, `call`, and `apply` all set `this` in the function's scope to an arbitrary object at run-time.  It certainly seems to be what the OP meant by "re-define" ... what do you mean when you say "re-define" that this answer doesn't address (so I can update it to be clearer)?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the function's `call` method.

```
someFunction.call(objectToBeThis, argument1, argument2, andSoOnAndSoOn);
```

Comment: +1 to the first answer that answers the most direct problem I posed. Checkmarked @Sean's answer though simply because it's more complete.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for..

```
functionRef.apply( objectContext, arguments);
```

Comment: +1 -- Also a good answer, though @Chuck's answer more directly does what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should of course learn to master `call()` and `apply()` as people have stated but a little helper never hurts...

In jQuery, there is [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/). In pure js, you can re-create that niftyness ;) with something like:

```
function proxyFn( fn , scope ){
  return function(){
     return fn.apply(scope,arguments);
  }
}
```

**Usage Examples:**

```
var myFunctionThatUsesThis = function(A,B){
  console.log(this,arguments); // {foo:'bar'},'a','b'
};

// setTimeout or do Ajax call or whatever you suppose loses "this"

var thisTarget = {foo: 'bar'};
setTimeout( proxyFn( myFunctionThatUsesThis, thisTarget) , 1000 , 'a', 'b' );

// or...

var contextForcedCallback = proxyFn( myAjaxCallback , someObjectToBeThis );
performAjaxRequest(myURL, someArgs, contextForcedCallback );
```

If you dont abuse it, it's a sure-fire tool to never loose the scope of "this".

Comment: Sorry, the original function I provided contained a mental lapsus. It has ben updated to the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

use a closure
i.e assign this to that early on; then you can do what you like with it.

```
var that = this;
```

Comment: Look at my example code. Note that the <s>event</s>function is being called from two places. How do you propose solving that with a closure without duplicating the content of `performAjaxRequest` ?